# Persist an object with a set<Object> (many to many)

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 tables : Service and Pays ,the relation between this 2 tables is many to many =>association :Payschoisis
When I persist in database , the object is saved without Hashset

Here my code :

Pays.hbm.xml

```
 <set name="services" table="payschoisis" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="id_pays" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="com.Dialpass.model.Service">
                <column name="id_service" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
```

Service.hbm.xml

```
  <set name="payses" table="payschoisis" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="id_service" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="com.Dialpass.model.Pays">
                <column name="id_pays" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
```

Pays.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "payses")
public Set<Service> getServices() {
    return this.services;
}

public void setServices(Set<Service> services) {
    this.services = services;
}
```

Service.java

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "payschoisis", catalog = "dialpass", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_service", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_pays", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<Pays> getPayses() {
        return this.payses;
    }

    public void setPayses(Set<Pays> payses) {
        this.payses = payses;
    }
```

And here where I Persist( The object is inserted correctly in database , but without Hashset even if set_pays is not empty

```
ServiceDsite si=new ServiceDsite();
            si.setNomService(getNom_service());
            si.setPayses(set_pays);
            serviceBo.addServicedsite(si);
```

the DAO function ::

```
@Override
    public void addServicedsite(ServiceDsite s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getHibernateTemplate().setCheckWriteOperations(false);
        getHibernateTemplate().save(s);

    }
```

PS: ServiceDsite is a subclass of Service ,
What can I do to make it working

Comment: So are you using XML mappings, or are you using annotations? Pick one then come back if you're still having issues. From docs: *You can mix annotated persistent classes and classic hbm.cfg.xml declarations with the same SessionFactory. ... [but] You cannot mix configuration strategies (hbm vs annotations) in an entity hierarchy ...*

Comment: Thank's for your answer , I removed annotation , but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your many to many mappings do not specify a mapping table.  (that would contain both primary keys of the mapped entities).  Here is a xml mapping example that shows how to specify that table which is necessary for Many to Many relationships.

```
<set name="categories" table="stock_category" 
        inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
        <key>
            <column name="STOCK_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="com.mkyong.stock.Category">
            <column name="CATEGORY_ID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
```

Comment: I have in mapping many to many table="payschoisis"  .. it's just like the example 
Thank's btw